# Run/Open a report with URL parameters

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

The idea is to call from outside of Cognos the link of the report with some parameters. So the user will not need to put the parameters when he opens the report. They will automatically filter the parameters. Using URL parameters or something like that.

I'm using the IBM Cognos Analytics 11.1 R7.

Someone know if this is possible? Have some tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible! Every piece of content has a share URL, and report prompt parameters can be added to the URL. More info here:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=mc-creating-custom-urls-display-run-cognos-analytics-content

Comment: TY for this link. But i can execute a report that has a prompt? When i try that, the URL just open the prompt without even set the parameters on the URL

Comment: You can suppress the report prompt page by adding &prompt=false to the URL.

Comment: Using the URL suggestion by @JeffWright, you could point the URL to a report view that has all the parameter values set instead of the report itself.  This way, you also get the benefit of being able to change the parameters in the view without changing the user's URL in the future.

Answer (score 1):

at the end of your report name add the parameters with what you want to put in.  for example:  Even if you want to run it in PDF that I have put at the end of the URL:

&run.prompt=false&p_pTEST=ABC&p_pPROMPT=TEST&run.prompt=false&run.outputFormat=PDF